# Create a gst-launch description from a coded gstreamer pipeline

Tags: gstreamer

Consider that I have coded a Gstreamer pipeline in C. How can I generate the text description of that pipeline so that I can use it on the command line with gst-launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gstreamer can create dot files of pipelines, though not the same format as gst-launch it gives me the information I'm looking for:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/debugging-tools.html

Answer (score -3):

You just need to dump the string which you pass as an input to gst_parse_launch() function. You can use exactly same string with gst launch command

Comment: Read the question carefully - gst_parse_launch() wasn't called yet, it was coded element by element.